# Access - Refresh combo when new records are entered

Tags: ms-access

See attached example: https://app.box.com/s/w2v0adawyyosokbv1guoo4994t845ffs

There's a combobox with a list of all the available part numbers.
The user can click on "part numbers registry" and add a new part number.
I need to refresh the combobox automatically each time a new part number is added/deleted.

I've put a requery macro on the "before update" event of my combobox control but it doesn't work.
I've tried all the other "on" events and none of the worked except "on double click" but as I've said, I'd rather update it automatically without any input from the user.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't let users delete part numbers. Mark them as inactive / superseded but don't delete, you'll lose any history and end up with duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select the `Partnumber` combobox and go to the Property `On Got Focus` select click on `...` and select `Code Builder` and add the following file

```
Me!PartNumber.Requery
```

it will fetch the new data whenever the combox got focus

OR

Use Macro

`Requery` and select `Partnumber`.

Comment: thanks. I've used the second method with the "got focus" event.